# What was the title of this IBM PC software compendium book circa mid 80s?

Tags: software, books

Sometime in the mid 90s I stopped by a library that used to sell off their old stock and bought a copy of an IBM PC software compendium that I am now struggling to remember the name of or find anywhere. This book was basically a listing of PC titles available at the time (including screenshots) and covered games, productivity software, etc.

The distinguishing features of this book were that it was a paperback with a black cover, approximately 8x11 inches in size, a fairly high page count with tiny text, and had a mono green-screen picture of the snake from "Adventure in Serenia" game by "On-Line Systems" (aka Sierra) on the back cover so I'm guessing that the book must have been pretty old by the time I bought it.

For those who have no idea what I'm talking about, here is the snake but it would have been rendered as a mono/green-screen image on the back cover:

[image: Screenshot of Adventure in Serenia courtesy of MobyGames]